# Is the circumflex significant in the word “Nazgûl”?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium, languages, tolkien-languages

I noticed how Nazgûl always has a circumflex (“^”) over the *u*. Does that mean anything about how I pronounce the word? Or is it just decoration?

Or, in other words:
What does the circumflex mean in Tolkien’s languages?

Comment: why all this negativeness?

Comment: Does your copy of the book have the appendices? I can't be positive but I thought they covered pronunciation.

Comment: It says that it means a long vowel in elvish, but id decoration in Adunaic and Dwarvish. So now we need to know what language 'Nagûl' is ;-)

Comment: I've always read it as meaning the pronounciation is something like naz-goul rather than naz-gul

Comment: Same as the "ö" in "Motörhead" :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From Appendix E, "Writing and Spelling":

> In Sindarin long vowels in stressed monosyllables are marked with the circumflex, since they tended in such cases to be specially prolonged; so in *dûn* compared with *Dúnadan*. The use of the circumflex in other languages such as Adûnaic or Dwarvish has no special significance, and is used merely to mark these out as alien tongues (as with the use of *k*).

Presumably Black Speech is included in the "other languages" here.

Comment: So is Nazgûl Black Speech?

Comment: Oh, it probably is since Nazg is Ring :-)

Comment: @MadTux From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nazgûl), `The Nazgûl (from Black Speech nazg, "ring", and gûl, "wraith, spirit")`

Comment: I seem to remember that the Black Speech doesn't have a written form.  The Ring is inscribed in Tengwar, so is it possible that the rules used to translate Tengwar also apply to the Black Speech?

Comment: @TGnat Good thinking!

Comment: So it's like a heavy metal umlaut then.  Cool.  Interestingly, BS is stated to have taken on influences from various Elvish tongues, so the -gûl in Nazgûl possibly has a relationship to the same element we see in Dol Guldur and Noldor.

Comment: Unless I'm misremembering, this quote is specifically talking about circumflex vs. acute. It does **not** say that the accents have no meaning at all (‘heavy metal umlaut’), only that the _form_ of the accent is unimportant in languages other than Sindarin. So _Nazgûl_ has a circumflex rather than an acute (_Nazgúl_) simply to mark it as foreign, but the presence of the accent itself is not unimportant: the accent denotes a long vowel, whatever its shape. _Nazgul_ would be pronounced differently.